# restricting a web based app logging from different tabs in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 for my front end.My requirement is to restrict the user from login to the app from other tabs.(user can log into the system only from one tab in the browser)

I have tried this in many ways.I stored a flag to the local storage and each time in app init i checked the flag.

```html
this.tokenHeader = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loginToken'));
    console.log("previous token", this.localStorage);
    if (this.tokenHeader !=null) {
      this.tokenError = true;

    }
    else {  // sign in process
    }
```

this works fine but if the tab or browser accidentally close (without proper logout) the local storage dose not removing.

also i tried to store a flag to the session storage but its not passing to the other tab.

Is there a proper way to keep the app running only from one tab.Please help me

Comment: How you are processing with localstorage ?

Comment: What should be the expected behavior if the user tries to open the app in another tab ? Should the user be prompted with login again ?

Comment: @SantoshSingh for a successful login I put a token to the local storage (loginToken).each time when the app loads/ in the app init i check the local storage and if the loginToken is not null I restrict the user to login

Comment: @NikilMathew of course , alert should be given to the user that he has logged from another app.

Comment: replace localStorage with sessionStorage?

Comment: you will have to remove `localStorage` data on `window.unload` also you have to maintain a flag in `sessionStorage` for every new tab so that you can identify that when on `unload` you need to clear `localStorage`.

Comment: @Carsten if i put a flag to the session storage can I check it from another tab ? is session storage unique to the tabs ?

Comment: I would recommend using session storage for such scenarios where in session is terminated as soon as the tab closes and the user is logged out as well